# Как сделать вращение координат мира вместе с вращением камеры в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, камера, move, rotate

Суть проблемы довольно простая:

Есть небольшой скрипт для вращения камеры вокруг объекта:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControls : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Target;
public float speed = 1f;

private void Update()
    {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) transform.RotateAround(Target.transform.position, 
    Vector3.up, 1f * speed);
    }
}
```

При нажатии на клавишу Q все работает, однако появляются проблемы с управлением персонажем.

К примеру:
Если не двигать камерой то клавиша W двигает персонажа ОТ игрока,
но если повернуть камеру на, скажем, 90 градусов - нажатие клавиши W смещает персонажа НАЛЕВО для игрока.

Возможно как то сделать так, чтобы вращение камерой также меняло и общую систему координат?

Comment: Вам не нужно менять никакую систему координат, вам нужно двигать объект в направлении, куда смотрит камера.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Миллион гайдов на YT, но, лучше вам сначала пойти на сайт юнити и пройти там курс, который даст вам начальные знания о движке, чтобы у вас таких вопросов в дальнейшем не было.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду учиться